# Backup my entire Ubuntu OS image like Norton Ghost used to. A GUI friendly and free method would be preferred

Tags: backup

I would like to backup my Ubuntu OS (I just got it all configured VBox additions and a couple VM's) and need a snapshot of it in the event something goes wrong. A simple GUI and free way would be preferred, in the past I have used Ghost on Windows ... but not sure the same/similar in Ubuntu land.  I have read many posts but most all of them are old and I'm looking for the best way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Clonezilla is your friend  http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: I am not able to get Clonezilla working, it keeps telling me that there are no existing partitions or not unmounted partitians are found ... i have used two versions and booting from the live cd ... any thoughts?

Comment: Just went and bought an external HDD ... hope that works better!